# Oauth server with Beast

Tags: boost-asio, keycloak, boost-beast

I know Beast is a low level library and does not come with OAuth build in by design. However, what options do I have to provide OAuth authentication for my Beast based server? Besides implementing OAuth on top of it (which I‘d rather want to avoid), what other possibilities do I have to achieve this? For example, is there a good way to integrate some existing auth server like Keycloak as an external instance?